# Read CSV file and put result in a map using Groovy (without using any external libraries)

Tags: groovy

I have a CSV file like below :

Sno,Service,Operation,ResponseTimeLimit
1,ProposalService,upsert,50
2,ScheduleService,getReservation,10
3,ScheduleService,bookAppointment,23

I would like to get this structure as the list of map as below :

[
[Sno:"1", Service:"ProposalService",Operation:"upsert",ResponseTimeLimit:"50"],
[Sno:"2",Service:"ScheduleService",Operation:"getReservation",ResponseTimeLimit:"10"],
[Sno:"3",Service:"ScheduleService",Operation:"bookAppointment",ResponseTimeLimit:"23"]
]

I got solution using CSVReader (OpenCSV). But can i do this WITHOUT USING any external references/libraries (like openCSV etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

If the structure of the CSV file will always be the same, you could do it with a Groovy script:

```
def mapList = []

File csvFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.csv")

csvFile.eachLine { line ->
    def parts = line.split(",")
    def tmpMap = [:]

    tmpMap.putAt("Sno", parts[0])
    tmpMap.putAt("Service", parts[1])
    // etc.

    mapList.add(tmpMap)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is another way to iterate all rows of the csv file:

```
def mapList = []
def headers = []
new File("/path/to/your/file.csv").readLines().eachWithIndex { row, rowIndex ->
    if (rowIndex == 0) { headers = row.split(',') }
    else {
        def tmpMap = [:]
        def cells = row.split(',').eachWithIndex { cell, cellIndex ->
          tmpMap[headers[cellIndex]] = cell
        }
        mapList.add(tmpMap)
    }
}
```

mapList result:

```
[[Sno:1, Service:ProposalService, Operation:upsert, ResponseTimeLimit:50], [Sno:2, Service:ScheduleService, Operation:getReservation, ResponseTimeLimit:10], [Sno:3, Service:ScheduleService, Operation:bookAppointment, ResponseTimeLimit:23]]
[Finished in 1.647s]`
```